# Hide the navigation controller view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [navigation bar show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926914/navigation-bar-show-hide)

I have a problem at hand.

I am displaying a navigation controller programmatically on an IPAD application specifically a kind of MODAL.
The modal is displayed on clicking the setting button.
Now i want to hide the controller view when the user signs up successfully or signs in successfully.
Can someone please tell me how to achieve this programatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you are presenting the NavigationController modally you can now dismiss it by using:

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to hide your navigation controller.

```
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]
```