# IOS pushViewController without tabBar and navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

How can I switch to a new view from tabBarController and navigationController and that there was no tabBar and navigationBar in a new view? And I need working swipe right for back old view.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
```

Comment: why do you want to push when you have no need for Nav and tabbar? you can simply present it with the button for the dismiss

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigation bar show/hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926914/navigation-bar-show-hide)

Comment: Example: http://oi61.tinypic.com/acdd89.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can hide in new view navigation bar in `viewWillAppear` method i.e. for navigationBar simply call `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```