# Using dismissViewController on queue of multiple UIViewControllers with delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm presenting a tutorial of 4 UIViewController when my app starts the first time.
Every UIViewController has a Button with a segue presenting the next ViewController.
The last ViewController has a button "Let's start" which should dismiss the tutorial completely.

**Problem:**
It this dismiss all ViewControllers except the first. I don't understand why?!

**What I expect:**

On the last ViewController4 I'm calling the dismissIntroduction() function of the first ViewController, so I except ALL ViewControllers (ViewController1 included) should disappear.
When I put a button on the first ViewController and call the function "dismissIntroduction()" it disappears.

**ViewController 1 (WelcomeViewController):**

```
protocol WelcomeViewDelegate {
    func dismissIntroduction()
}

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, WelcomeViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func dismissIntroduction() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
        destination.delegate = self
    }

}
```

**ViewController 2:**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var delegate:WelcomeViewDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }        

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController3
        destination.delegate = self.delegate
    }

}
```

**ViewController 3:**

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    var delegate:WelcomeViewDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }        

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController4
        destination.delegate = self.delegate
    }

}
```

**ViewController4 (the last one):**

```
class ViewController4: UIViewController {

    var delegate:WelcomeViewDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func pressLetsStart(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.delegate!.dismissIntroduction()
    }

}
```

***EDIT:***
I got it working, when I put the dismissViewControllerAnimated function TWO times!?

```
func dismissIntroduction() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

But why? I don't understand the logic behind...

Comment: did you try having this all four controllers in navigation controller and present NavController  from let say PPViewContoller ?

Comment: I don't want to put it in a navigation controller (because of the navigation bar).

Comment: you can always hide the navigation bar like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926914/navigation-bar-show-hide, doing by apple way(navigation controller) is a better approach than running into many bugs or maintenance mare in long run..

Comment: Thanks mkumar, I'll try this. That sounds really like a clean solution

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong solution to your problem, what you need to do is look for Unwind Segues. Go through this tutorial: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem now with following function in last ViewController:

```
@IBAction func pressLetsStart(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissModalStack()
}

private func dismissModalStack() {
    var vc = self.presentingViewController! as UIViewController
    while (vc.presentingViewController != nil) {
        vc = vc.presentingViewController!;
    }
    vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```